# Create arbitrary sized in-memory file with python

Tags: python, pytest

I am in the process of writing integration tests for an S3 bucket. I therefore need to programmatically create files which I can use in my tests for up- and downloading.

I'm basically looking for a solution similar to how I would do it in bash, i.e.:

```
mkfile -n 1g ~/Desktop/MyTestFile
```

Opposed to above, I would however like to create the empty file as a memory stream.

Comment: Do you have to use the `s3_client.upload_file()` method to upload the file or can it be a different `s3_client` method?

Comment: I am using `s3_client.upload_part()` to be exact. I just need at least 5MB to be able to test my multipart upload. I mocked the client with [moto3](https://pypi.org/project/moto/) - I'm not aware if there is a way around it, with this library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up doing this:

```
size = 10000000

with BytesIO() as buffer: 
    buffer.write(bytearray(os.urandom(size)))
    buffer.seek(0)
    ...
    #Use my buffer to do some logic
```

It does the trick - i.e. writing a random string to a bytes array and persists it in a `BytesIO` memorystream.